# How to connect to SAP from Salesforce with the SAP SD wsdl

Tags: api, integration, webservices, wsdl2apex

Having SAP SD WSDL file how can I connect to SAP from Salesforce ?

After connecting with salesforce, I only want to view the data.

1.Now i convert this WSDL file into apex classes next step what can i do for that.

kindly anyone tell how to resolve this. Thanks, Regards, Udaya

Comment: Asking the same question twice won't make a difference, please read the FAQ:
You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: Perhaps the question for you is, what kind of protocols do you intend to use to connect from within Salesforce to your SAP services that are hosted elsewhere? Do you know what web services you currently have configured in Salesforce? Will you be using REST, SOAP, etc? How will you authenticate?  Those are just a few of many questions one could ask you. I'd highly recommend you do some research, then come back with questions that are much more specific than what you're asking.